# org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, hadoop2, apache-zeppelin

Error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: Call From ip-10-0-1-215.us-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.215 to ppp-58-8-16-250.revip2.asianet.co.th:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=ppp-58-8-16-250.revip2.asianet.co.th/58.8.16.250:8020]; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout
```

Scala code:

```
val numTerms = 50000
val sampleSize = 0.1
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("Wiki LSA")
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

def preprocessing(sampleSize: Double, numTerms: Int, sc: SparkContext)
      : (RDD[Vector], Map[Int, String], Map[Long, String], Map[String, Double]) = {
    val pages = readFile("hdfs://localhost:/user/hduser/wikidump.xml", sc)
      .sample(false, sampleSize, 11L)

    val plainText = pages.filter(_ != null).flatMap(wikiXmlToPlainText)

    val stopWords = sc.broadcast(loadStopWords("/home/ubuntu/aas/ch06-lsa/target/classes/stopwords.txt")).value

    val lemmatized = plainText.mapPartitions(iter => {
      val pipeline = createNLPPipeline()
      iter.map{ case(title, contents) => (title, plainTextToLemmas(contents, stopWords, pipeline))}
    })

val (termDocMatrix, termIds, docIds, idfs) = preprocessing(sampleSize, numTerms, sc)


Zeppelin version - 0.7.0
Spark version - 1.6.2
Hadoop version - 2.6.4
Scala code runner version - 2.9.2 
EC2 instance - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-215:~/spark$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-215:~/spark$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.7-SNAPSHOT (58348a8971e0fb4cf26a281f1cf0f2ce3af9f0c9; 2015-08-17T08:31:09+00:00)
Maven home: /home/ubuntu/apps/maven/apache-maven-3.3.x-SNAPSHOT
Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-92-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-215:~/spark$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.6.4
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 5082c73637530b0b7e115f9625ed7fac69f937e6
Compiled by jenkins on 2016-02-12T09:45Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 8dee2286ecdbbbc930a6c87b65cbc010
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.4.jar


val (termDocMatrix, termIds, docIds, idfs) = preprocessing(sampleSize, numTerms, sc)

org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: Call From ip-10-0-1-215.us-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.215 to ppp-58-8-16-250.revip2.asianet.co.th:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=ppp-58-8-16-250.revip2.asianet.co.th/58.8.16.250:8020]; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:752)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1988)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1644)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:385)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PartitionwiseSampledRDD.getPartitions(PartitionwiseSampledRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$zipWithUniqueId$1.apply(RDD.scala:1286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$zipWithUniqueId$1.apply(RDD.scala:1285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.zipWithUniqueId(RDD.scala:1285)
    at com.cloudera.datascience.lsa.ParseWikipedia$.documentTermMatrix(ParseWikipedia.scala:48)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$bec1ee5c9e2e4d5af247761bdfbc3b3$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.preprocessing(<console>:190)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$bec1ee5c9e2e4d5af247761bdfbc3b3$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:176)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$5acc5a6ce0af8ab20753597dcc84fc0$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:185)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$5acc5a6ce0af8ab20753597dcc84fc0$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:187)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$5acc5a6ce0af8ab20753597dcc84fc0$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:189)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$5acc5a6ce0af8ab20753597dcc84fc0$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:191)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$5acc5a6ce0af8ab20753597dcc84fc0$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:193)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:195)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:197)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:199)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:201)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:203)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:205)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$725d9ae18728ec9520b65ad133e3b55$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:207)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$725d9ae18728ec9520b65ad133e3b55$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:209)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$725d9ae18728ec9520b65ad133e3b55$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:211)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$725d9ae18728ec9520b65ad133e3b55$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:213)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$725d9ae18728ec9520b65ad133e3b55$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:215)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:217)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:219)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:221)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:223)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:225)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$ad149dbdbd963d0c9dc9b1d6f07f5e$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:227)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$ad149dbdbd963d0c9dc9b1d6f07f5e$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:229)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$ad149dbdbd963d0c9dc9b1d6f07f5e$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:231)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$ad149dbdbd963d0c9dc9b1d6f07f5e$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:233)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$ad149dbdbd963d0c9dc9b1d6f07f5e$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:235)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$6e49527b15a75f3b188beeb1837a4f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:237)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$6e49527b15a75f3b188beeb1837a4f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:239)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$6e49527b15a75f3b188beeb1837a4f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:241)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$6e49527b15a75f3b188beeb1837a4f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:243)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$6e49527b15a75f3b188beeb1837a4f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:245)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$93297bcd59dca476dd569cf51abed168$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:247)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$93297bcd59dca476dd569cf51abed168$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:249)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$93297bcd59dca476dd569cf51abed168$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:251)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$93297bcd59dca476dd569cf51abed168$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:253)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$93297bcd59dca476dd569cf51abed168$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:255)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:257)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:259)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:261)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:263)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:265)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:267)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:269)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:271)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:273)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:275)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:277)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:279)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:281)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:283)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:285)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:287)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:289)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:291)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:293)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:295)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:297)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:299)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:301)
    at <init>(<console>:303)
    at .<init>(<console>:307)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:704)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:912)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:858)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:851)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:94)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:383)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=ppp-58-8-16-250.revip2.asianet.co.th/58.8.16.250:8020]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 169 more
```

Comment: Coming in very late here, but did you have any luck? Do you recall what did you do to solve this? It'd be great help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you hadoop is working fine, run the below commands

nc -vz $hostname 8020  => hostname where hadoop is running and try to close the firewall is that is open as well.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-215:~/spark$ nc -vz localhost 8020
Connection to localhost 8020 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

Comment: Port 8020 is open in my EC2 security group.

Comment: This command run with no problem: hadoop fs -put /hdfs/wikidump.xml /user/hduser/wikidump.xml